# Negative coefficient in an almost cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Let $a,b,c,d$ be four prime numbers. We set the polynomial :
$$P(X)=\frac{(1-X^{abc})(1-X^{abd})(1-X^{acd})(1-X^{bcd})(1-X^a)(1-X^b)(1-X^c)(1-X^d)}{(1-X)^2(1-X^{ab})(1-X^{ac})(1-X^{ad})(1-X^{bc})(1-X^{bd})(1-X^{cd})}$$
By numerical tests, i see that $P(X)$ always has at least one negative coefficient, how can i prove it?

Comment: Related question I asked at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/214784/which-sets-of-roots-of-unity-give-a-polynomial-with-nonnegative-coefficients

Comment: Note that $P(x)=\prod \Phi_m(x)$, where the product is over all $1<m<abcd$ dividing $abcd$.

Comment: @Louis the references you give seem really interesting...

Comment: When we write $P(X)=\prod \phi_{m}(X)$ it's not obvious for me that we can deduce the sign of the coefficient of $P$.
For exemple if we consider 
$$Q(X)=\frac{(1-X^{ab})(1-X^{ac})(1-X^{bc})}{(1-X^{a})(1-X^{b})(1-X^{c})}$$ we have also $Q(X)=\prod \phi_{m}(X)$ but in this case it's clear that $Q$ only has non negative coefficient.

Comment: Yes, I certainly agree with you.  My observation above is well short of answering the question, sadly.  I'd also like to see how this could be resolved.  I'd also  be interested in knowing how this question came up to begin with, if it's at all easy to explain.

Comment: At first, i was studying some orthogonal function (in control theory) and more specifically its sign. The orthogonal function depends of four parameters and its linked with a polynomial (such as the one of the question). After a big number of numerical tests, i observe that when i take the parameters in the form $(abc,abd,acd,bcd)$ the polynomial always has a negative coefficient (that is important to understand the orthogonal function).
I don't know if it's clear, it is always complicated to summarize a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that $a<b<c<d$. We show that the coefficient of $X^c$ or of $X^{b+c-1}$ of $P(X)$ is negative. In order to do so, it suffices to work in the power series ring $\mathbb Q[[X]]$ modulo $X^{b+c}$. Note that $ac>b+c$ and so on, hence
\begin{equation}
P(X)\equiv\frac{(1-X^a)(1-X^b)(1-X^c)(1-X^d)}{(1-X)^2(1-X^{ab})}\pmod{X^{b+c}}.
\end{equation}
Set
\begin{equation}
F(X)=\frac{1-X^a}{1-X}\cdot\frac{1-X^b}{1-X}\cdot\frac{1}{1-X^{ab}}=(1+\dots+X^{a-1})(1+\dots+X^{b-1})(1+X^{ab}+\dots),
\end{equation}
so $P(X)\equiv F(X)(1-X^c-X^d)$ (recall that $c+d>b+c$).

For a power series $G$ let $G[k]$ be the coefficient of $X^k$.

So $P[k]=F[k]-F[k-c]-F[k-d]$.

The coefficients of $F$ lie between $0$ and $a$, and $F[k]=a$ if an only if the remainder of $k\pmod{ab}$ lies between $a-1$ and $b-1$. Furthermore, $F[k]=0$ if the remainder of $k\pmod{ab}$ lies between $a+b-1$ and $ab-1$.

Now assume that $P[b+c-1]\ge0$. From $P[b+c-1]=F[b+c-1]-F[b-1]-F[b+c-1-d]$ and $F[b-1]=a$ we infer that $F[b+c-1]=a$. Thus the remainder of $(b+c-1)\pmod{ab}$ lies between $a-1$ and $b-1$. This implies that the remainder of $c\pmod{ab}$, call it $r$, fulfills $ab+a-b\le r\le ab-1$ or $r=0$. The latter cannot happen, because then $a$ would divide the prime $c$. Thus the former holds. But $a+b-1\le ab+a-b$, hence $F[c]=0$.

But then $P[c]=F[c]-F[0]=0-1=-1$, and we are done.

Comment: Another choice of the exponent which works is the minimal $k\geq c$ such that $(k\mod ab)\geq a+b-1$.